# Invoke Invocable Actions through REST API

Tags: flow, custom-actions

I am trying to invoke custom actions through REST API.

I created a HelloWorld Autolaunched Flow which updates Billing Address of Account and then sends out email so that i can get confirmation that flow got executed successfully.
when i manually click on Run from the list of flows, Accounts are updated and i am able to receive email notification.

Then I tried to invoke the Flow from REST API.

```
https://na31.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/actions/custom/flow/HelloWorld_Flow
```

flow does not have any input so my json payload is

```
{
  "inputs": []
}
```

I receive 200 status of Success however the Accounts are not updated and also email notification is not sent out.

Is there any configuration/setting/permission for REST API to invoke flow?
or is my REST API call is having wrong data?

note: if i add at least one input to the flow and pass input value in json payload then entire flow works on REST invoke but in real i do not need any input.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me .I would just open a case with support

Comment: please  share case details with me

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the delay.
I got to the same problem today.

I found this Salesforce article that helped me.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_system_rest.htm&type=5

In short, you need to use in Body:

```
{
     "inputs" : [{}]
}
```

In your case, "{}" is missing, inside the Inputs.